# Fluent CRUD with NHibernate ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, controller, crud

ASP.NET MVC makes it really easy to create editing templates for simple, flat objects. But managing CRUD for complex objects with several indirections when using something like Fluent NHibernate, is not so obvious.

## Example

To illustrate my question with a simple Invoice manager, *Invoice* entities have a *Project* property:

```
public class Invoice
{
    ...
    Project Project { get; set; } // where Project class has an Id and a Name
}
```

...which is mapped to the `Projects` table via Fluent NHibernate in my `InvoiceMap`:

```
References(x => x.Project).Inverse();
```

In the past, my Invoice entities would have a `ProjectId` property that referenced a project in my database, which made it easier to render a select list with Project IDs, but harder to output views, e.g.:

```
public class Invoice
{
    ...
    Guid ProjectID { get; set; }
}
```

But since I started using Fluent NHibernate, I don't want to dirty up my controller with more IDs.

### `InvoiceController`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    var invoice = _unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Get<Invoice>(id);
    return View(invoice);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Invoice invoice)
{
    /* How to deal with invoice.Project mapping here without introducing a second
       action parameter, e.g. Guid projectId ? */

    _unitOfWork.CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(invoice);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = invoice.Id });
}
```

The referenced *Project* should not be editable from my *Invoice/Edit.cshtml* view, but I want to be able to choose which Project the Invoice should belong to.

How should I design my views and controllers to make CRUD easy without cluttering up my controller action with reference IDs that are not flat entity fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you create an action on your ProjectController (assuming you have one) which has a partial view which is simply a list of the projects.

e.g.

```
 public class ProjectController : Controller
 {
      public ActionResult ProjectsList()
      {   
          var projects = GetAllProjects();
          return View(projects);
      }
 }
```

Project/ProjectsList.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Data.Models.Project>
@{ Layout = null }
<select name="project">
 @foreach(var project in Model)
 {
   <option value="@project.Id">@project.Name</option>
 } 
</select>
```

Invoice/Edit.cshtml

```
<label>Title</label>
<input name="title" />

@Html.Action("ProjectsList","Project")
```

I would then change you Edit invoice to take an input model rather than the straight invoice and look up the project by Id in that action.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! Just found a [good link](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/13/developing-web-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-and-ef-code-first-part-2.aspx) with an example of using a view model as the input for the Invoice/Edit action. I've just always found the word "view model" confusing for this, though.

Comment: @Rob, how about modifying the Invoice EditorTemplate so the Invoice/Edit view can use the `Html.EditorFor(invoice => x.Project)` syntax? If possible, how can I wire it up to my `ProjectController`?

Comment: I tend to call them InputModel and ViewData to avoid mixing up the terminology.

Comment: @FreshCode I'm not sure EditorFor can do that complex an editor.

Comment: Do you use AutoMapper to map your fields?

Comment: @Rob, would you also have an `InvoiceViewModel` along with an `InvoiceInputModel`?

Comment: @FreshCode I often do yes. It depends on the situation. I'm still learning Mvc as well, I worry that all these POCOs is a bit much but it seems to be the best way so far and I am using AutoMapper - be sure to check NHProf when using it with nhibernate objects though. Mapping lazy loaded properties often leads to Select N+1 problems.

Comment: @Rob, see my new question, [How should AutoMapper access my DAL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636961/how-should-automapper-access-my-dal) for more in-detail queries about this.