# Need nHibernate Guide to do CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I need some tutorials on how to make CRUD using nhibernate in ASP.net MVC. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://sdesmedt.wordpress.com/2006/06/13/nhibernate-part-2-crud-with-nhibernate/) is a turorial on CRUD in nhibernate and [here](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/12/testing-crud-operations-with-nhibernate/) is a post describing how to test CRUD operations.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635588/fluent-crud-with-nhibernate-asp-net-mvc) stackoverflow post.  Look at the sidebar on this page to find many more posts on nhibernate